# Как расширить TypeScript-интерфейс из библиотеки, если она была импортирована под другими именем?

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, intellisense

[Определения типов TypeScript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vinyl/index.d.ts) к библиотеке [Vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl) позволяют нам добавлять новые свойства к экземпляру `File`, потому при самых строгих настройках TypeScript не будет на это ругаться:

```
interface File {
  contents: Buffer | NodeJS.ReadableStream | null;

  // ...

  [customProperty: string]: any;
}
```

Всё замечательно, но без автодополнений, которые предоставляют современные интегрированные среды разработки (например, IntelliJ IDEA), повышается вероятность ошибки ввода, а TypeScript её не заметит, потому что нам позволено добавлять сколько угодно новых свойств к `File`. На данный момент предлагаются автодополнения только тех свойств, которые указаны в [@types/vynil/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/vinyl/index.d.ts). Вероятно, если расширить интерфейс `File`, который даёт Vynil, до среда разработки его заметит и начнёт предлагать также пользовательские свойства в качестве автодополнений.

Это вопрос назывался бы "как расширить TypeScript интерфейс сторонней библиотеки", если не одно "но": поскольку интерфейс `File` уже занят типами к стандартным NodeJS-модулям, то я импортирую не `import File from 'vinyl';`, а
`import Vinyl from 'vinyl';`. Это даёт возможность аннотировать Vynil-экземпляры как `Vynil`, а не `File`:

```
// ...

return gulp.src(entryPointsSourceFilesAbsolutePaths)
        .pipe(this.gulpPlugins.intercept((fileInInitialState: Vinyl) => {
            fileInInitialState.selfSourceVersionAbsolutePath = fileInInitialState.path;
            return fileInInitialState;
        }))
// ...
```

Итак, где, под каким именем и каким образом я должен расширить TypeScript-интерфейс библиотеки Vylil, что бы с точки зрения TypeScript-а это было правильное расширение интерфейса? (Тогда IDE с большой вероятностью начнёт показывать автодополнения и для моих свойств, в том числе `selfSourceVersionAbsolutePath` из примера выше).

---

### Фрагмент из определений к vynil с комментарием

```
/// <reference types="node" />

import * as fs from 'fs';

interface ConstructorOptions {
   // .. 
}

interface FileConstructor {
    // ...
    prototype: File;
}

export = File;

declare let File: FileConstructor;

interface File {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

уточняющий вопрос.
а то, что импортируется из 'vinyl' по умолчанию - это точно интерфейс? (не знаю что это за библиотека, а проверять не хочу).
если интерфейс, то предлагаю такой вариант:

```
import Vinyl from 'vinyl';

interface IExtendedVinyl extends Vinyl { 
  selfSourceVersionAbsolutePath: string; // или что там у вас
}

const myFunc = (fileInInitialState: IExtendedVinyl) => {...};
```

я спрашиваю потому, что интерфейс можно унаследовать только от другого интерфейса.
если же это вдруг не интерфейс, то предлагаю использовать объединение типов:

```
import Vinyl from 'vinyl';

type TExtendedVinyl = Vinyl & { 
  selfSourceVersionAbsolutePath: string; // или что там у вас
};

const myFunc = (fileInInitialState: TExtendedVinyl) => {...};
```

Собственно если Vinyl это интерфейс, то объединение типов тоже сработает.

И да, поле selfSourceVersionAbsolutePath в этом случае появится в автодополнении, как и все то что вы руками пропишете.

P.S. Из модуля еще может экспортироваться нэймспейс, и тогда предложенные варианты не сработают. Но судя по тому что вы пишете fileInInitialState: Vinyl, это не так.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Пригляделся внимательнее к определениям - там всё запутанно (добавил в вопрос). Да, импортирован интерфейс, но я не понял, что именно импортировано по именем `File`: сам интерфейс `File`, который соответствует экземепляру Vinyl-файла,  или же `FileConstructor`.

Comment: @Боков Глеб весьма интересно. я над этим никогда не задумывался, спасибо что заставили покопаться - я все же поставил эту библиотеку (точнее только типы) и посмотрел что там. судя по всему импортируется некая сущность, которая ведет себя по разному в зависимости от того что с ней делают. так IDE разрешает мне писать как interface ISome extends Vinyl (ведет себя как интерфейс), так и const vin = new Vinyl (ведет себя как класс)

Comment: не знаю как там в IntelliJ IDEA, но в VS Code когда наводишь на импортированную сущность, то он пишет: https://github.com/muturgan/muturgan.github.io/blob/master/Screenshot%20from%202019-08-21%2014-16-38.png  слово alias намекает

Comment: кстати говоря никто не запрещает вам импортировать File из "vinyl" если вы не импортируете сущность с таким же названием откуда-то еще в этом же файле

Comment: кстати интерфейсы оказывается можно наследовать не только от интерфейсов но и от классов - век живи век учись и дураком помрешь)

Comment: И Вам спасибо за ответ! Ввиду того, что технологии веб-разработки развиваются очень быстро, наши знания просто быстро устаревают, потому слово "дурак" тут не очень уместно :) Ну а поскольку благодаря Вашему ответу я свою проблему решил, по я его принимаю и даю Вам очки репутации.